# React dispatch is not defined remove action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have a problem with my actionsFormatter.

When I click on the DELETE button, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined at onClick

How could I fix this problem?

```
import { removeEnvironnement } from '../../actions/environnement';
const EnvironnementList = (props) => (

            <BootstrapTable 
                keyField='id' 
                data={ props.store.environnements } 
                columns={ columns }
                selectRow={selectRow} 
                pagination={ paginationFactory() } 
                filter={ filterFactory() } 
                striped hover condensed
              />
);

const actionsFormatter  = (cell, row) => {
    const id=row.id
    return (
            <button className="btn btn-danger" 
                onClick={() => {
                     dispatch(removeEnvironnement({ id }));}}
            >Delete</button>
    );
};

const columns = [{
    dataField: 'id',
    text: 'ID'
}, {
    dataField: 'nom',
    text: 'Nom',
    filter: textFilter()
}, {
    dataField: 'actions',
    text: 'Action',
    formatter: actionsFormatter
} ];


const selectRow = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    bgColor: '#00BFFF'
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        store: state
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EnvironnementList);
```

Here is my code to do the remove :
Should I remove the dispatch part?

```
const _removeEnvironnement = ({ id } = {}) => ({
    type: 'REMOVE_ENVIRONNEMENT',
    id
});

export const removeEnvironnement = ({ id } = {}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.delete(`environnements/${id}`).then(() => {
            dispatch(_removeEnvironnement({ id }));
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `dispatch` in your `actionsFormatter`? It is defined neither on `actionsFormatter` scope nor on out of `actionsFormatter` scope. That's the problem and that's the javascript interpreter talking you about.

One of the possible fix is to import you redux store

store.js

```
export const store = createStore(...)
```

EnvironmentList.js

```
import { store } from './path/to/store.js'

// ...

const actionsFormatter  = (cell, row) => {
    const { dispatch } = store
    const id = row.id
    // ...
};
```

This way you'll get `dispatch` available in `actionsFormatter` body.

---

Another way is to provide mapped method via connect -> EnvironmentList -> actionsFormatter chain. Do what Arnaud Christ suggested [in his reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295706/3211932) and then refactor the code:

```
const EnvironmentList = (props) => (

            <BootstrapTable 
                keyField='id' 
                data={ props.store.environnements } 
                columns={ columns(props.removeEnvironment) }
                selectRow={selectRow} 
                pagination={ paginationFactory() } 
                filter={ filterFactory() } 
                striped hover condensed
              />
);

const actionsFormatter = (removeEnvironment) => (cell, row) => {
    const id=row.id
    return (
            <button className="btn btn-danger" 
                onClick={() => {
                     removeEnvironment({ id });
                }}
            >Delete</button>
    );
};

const columns = (removeEnvironment) => [{
    dataField: 'id',
    text: 'ID'
}, {
    dataField: 'nom',
    text: 'Nom',
    filter: textFilter()
}, {
    dataField: 'actions',
    text: 'Action',
    formatter: actionsFormatter(removeEnvironment)
} ];
```

So, the connected EnvironmentList got necessary removeEnvironment method on it's props. Then we passes it to columns creator, which passed it to actionsFormatter creator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link your component with the `dispatch` method.

As you are already using `react-redux` to connect your component to your Redux store, you can easily do that through mapping `dispatch` to `props`.

Just add the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        store: state
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        removeEnvironnement: id => {
             dispatch(removeEnvironnement({ id }));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EnvironnementList);
```

And then in your onClick handler, just call `this.props.removeEnvironnement(id)`

Comment: Thank, but when i make : this.props.removeEnvironnement(id). I have : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: It depends of your need. Just wrap any component with the `connect` HOC with `mapDispatchToProps` as parameter and it will have access to `removeEnvironnement` in its own `props`.